# Creating a development and staging environments for Google Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am working on a project that has a dev environment and a staging environment, and thus each environment has its own servers, databases, and each environment should also have its own Pub/Subs and Cloud Functions.

I have a Cloud Function called `jsonToCsv` that exports a function with the same name `jsonToCsv`, I want to deploy the same code but under a different name i.e. `jsonToCsv_staging`, however, GCloud won't allow me to export a function with a name different from the Cloud Function's

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, 
message=Function load error: Node.js module defined by file index.js is 
expected to export function named jsonToCsv-staging
```

Coming from an AWS background, I thought there would be a way for me to call different versions of the Cloud Function (i.e. latest would be development and I'd be able to tag a version with `staging` and another one with `production`) but I couldn't find a way to do that.

The one way I can think of to get around this is to use the same function with the same name but different Pub/Subs or triggers that would pass environment variables. That wouldn't work if the developer wants to deploy some development code without affecting staging. What are your thoughts on this? What's the best practice in that scenario?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The recommended way to isolate environments in Google Cloud Platform (and therefore also Firebase) is to create different projects for each environment.

Environment multi-tenancy in GCP projects is kind of a bad idea, as it opens you up to relatively easy corruption of your production data and code to the daily workings of your development practices.

Comment: Ultimately you are correct Doug, but unfortunately, I am not in control of the DevOps (but I'll recommend doing that anyway) so komarkovich's workaround works for me until the environments are separated.

Comment: Different projects for the environments? Doesnt that require a lot of setup and maintenance to keep the two versions synced (eg you deploy a new functionality, youll need to do it on both ends)? Or is there a smart way to copy projects? How do you check if the two projects are in sync?

Comment: @JohnAndrews yes, it can take some effort if you want to copy a project. But I would argue that you don't want to have that happen automatically, since that would be disruptive. It's good to find a solid "working set" of data that you can use to bootstrap a project so that it's predictable to test and dev against.

Comment: How would one transfer/update the production project - from the development project?

Answer (score 4):

By the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/filesystem#deploy_using_the_gcloud_tool) you can see that unless you specify the `--entry-point` option, your module must export a function with the same name.

Adding the `--entry-point` to the command will allow you to use different names for Cloud Functions with the same exporting function.

Your command should look something like this:

```
gcloud beta functions deploy jsonToCsv_staging --entry-point jsonToCsv --trigger-resource <my-topic> --trigger-event google.pubsub.topic.publish
```